# Acessando métodos do Animator Unity 2019

Tags: unity3d

Boa tarde pessoal eu estou com a seguinte duvida, eu criei umas animações no Animator da unity 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a duvida é o seguinte como eu acesso os metodos crados no animator via script como o grounded ali e o id Animation, eu vi dessa forma na internet mas parece que n funciona

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class aulaScript : MonoBehaviour{

```
private Animator playerAnimator;

public bool Grounded;
public int idAnimation;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start(){
    playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update(){
    playerAnimator.setBool("grounded", Grounded);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

É só alterar

```
playerAnimator.SetBool("grounded", Grounded);
```

para

```
playerAnimator.SetBool("grounded", true);
```

Comment: Assets\Scripts\aulaScript.cs(19,24): error CS1061: 'Animator' does not contain a definition for 'setBool' and no accessible extension method 'setBool' accepting a first argument of type 'Animator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Desculpa no caso é 
SetBool 
não
setBool
vou editar a resposta